# count and retrieve objects of polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, statistics

So i've got three models

```
"Text" has_many :statistics, :as => :loggable
"Document" has_many :statistics, :as => :loggable
"Statistic" belongs_to :loggable, :polymorphic => true
"Company" has_many "Documents"/"Texts"
```

now i want to get different restults, f.e.

- get the total count of statistic objects of all text/document objects of a company
- get the total count of statistic objects of all text/document objects of a company
  this month
- get the first five Texts/Documents of a company with the most statistic
  objects
- get the first five Texts/Documents of a company with the most statistic
  objects this month

this month is related to the creation date of the statistic object.

i really have no idea how to achieve this. i tried different things in the rails console but without luck.

```
company.texts
company.documents
```

any ideas how to do this?
thanks in advance. please leave a comment if something is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first 2 are pretty simple.

get the total count of statistic objects of all text/document objects

```
Statistic.where(:loggable_type => "Text").where(:loggable_id => company.texts)
```

get the total count of statistic objects of all text/document objects this month

```
Statistic.where('created_at between ? and ?', 1.month.ago, Time.now).where(:loggable_type => "Text").where(:loggable_id => d.texts).count
```

get the first five Texts/Documents of a company with the most statistic objects

```
ids = Statistic.select("COUNT(*) AS count_all").where(:loggable_type => "Text").where(:loggable_id => company.texts).group(:loggable_id).order("count_all desc").limit(5).size
Text.where(:id => ids)
```

get the first five Texts/Documents of a company with the most statistic objects this month

```
ids = Statistic.select("COUNT(*) AS count_all").where('created_at between ? and ?', 1.month.ago, Time.now).where(:loggable_type => "Text").where(:loggable_id => d.texts).group(:loggable_id).order("count_all desc").limit(5).size
Text.where(:id => ids)
```

Comment: Just an addition: It will only work with the singular class Name -> Statistic (not Statistics)

Comment: oh sorry, i was not clear enough. see my edits above. for the first two i need "the total count of all text models related to a given company" AND the total count of all company models related to a given company". seperated, not combined

Comment: So this will get all statistics where the type is Text, but not where the text is related to the given company. any ideas how to do this on a given array of texts (`company.texts`)?

Comment: Unless I am completely missing the point, you want `company.texts.count`?

Comment: `company.texts.(all statistics of all of this text objects).count` something like that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6735/discussion-between-gazler-and-choise)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
company.texts.join(:statistics).where('statistics.created_at between ? and ?', Time.now, 1.month.ago)
```

and

```
company.documents.join(:statistics).where('statistics.created_at between ? and ?', Time.now, 1.month.ago)
```